# how can I scroll text box down one by one line

Tags: html, scroll, textarea

below code is input text area. When I click scroll arraw to the down; it jump 3 line. But It should be one by one line down when clicked down button.

Do you know any attribute or html tag for this ?

```
<textarea id="mus" class="input-medium" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:13px;font-size:10px;" rows="1"
                                            readonly="true" >
```

Comment: AFAIK that is a function of the user's computer, not the website.

Comment: what is the meaning AFAIK ?

Comment: [As Far As I Know](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK).

Comment: jsf service using on this case.